# How to align 3 images with width 100%

Tags: html, css, carousel

I will make a carousel and i try to align left  3 elements with width 100% each but it is not working.

Can someone tell me how to align 3,4 elements on left to get out of the screens witdh so that i can change the image with the transform css property ?

it worked when i delete from the top of the page  but when i insert it,everything is ruined.

```css
.carousel {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.carousel--list {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.carousel--slide {
  background: #000;
  text-align: center;
  color:#fff;
  width:100%;
  display: inline-block;

  overflow: hidden;
  height: 400px;
  padding: 0;
}

.carousel--track{
  width: auto;
  -webkit-transition: transform 2s;
   transition: transform 2s;
}

.carousel--buttons {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

.slide--image {
  width: 100%;
}
.red{
  background: red;

}

.blue{
  background: blue;
}

.yellow{
  background: yellow;
}
/* transform .*/
```

```html
<section class="carousel">
  <div class="carousel--track">
    <div class="carousel--list">
      <div class="carousel--slide red" data-index="0">
        <img class="slide--image" src="./images/carousel/slider-bg.png">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel--slide blue" data-index="1">
    <img class="slide--image" src="./images/carousel/slider-bg.png">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel--slide yellow" data-index="2">
            <img class="slide--image" src="./images/carousel/slider-bg.png">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<div class="carousel--buttons">
  <button onclick="prevSlide()" class="btn--prev btn">Prev</button>
  <button onclick="nextSlide()" class="btn--next btn">Next</button>
</div>
</section>
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Check out flexbox. [Here is an awesome guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to learn it quickly.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [flexbox](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) or [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/). With those you will be able to edit your code as a gride and place elements where you wan't.

Flexbox is a css engine. Maybe what you need !

Example for [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) :

[image]

And [flexbox](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Apply `white-space: nowrap` to the parent `.carousel--list` class...It will wrap all the inner `inline-block` items in a single row.

***Note***: I have applied `transform(-30px)` to the `.carousel--list` to give you a visual

***Stack Snippet***

```css
.carousel {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.carousel--list {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transform: translateX(-30px);
}

.carousel--slide {
  background: #000;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 0;
}

.carousel--track {
  width: auto;
  -webkit-transition: transform 2s;
  transition: transform 2s;
}

.carousel--buttons {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

.slide--image {
  width: 100%;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
}

.yellow {
  background: yellow;
}


/* transform .*/
```

```html
<section class="carousel">
  <div class="carousel--track">
    <div class="carousel--list">
      <div class="carousel--slide red" data-index="0">
        <img class="slide--image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150/f00">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel--slide blue" data-index="1">
        <img class="slide--image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150/00f">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel--slide yellow" data-index="2">
        <img class="slide--image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150/f0f">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel--buttons">
    <button onclick="prevSlide()" class="btn--prev btn">Prev</button>
    <button onclick="nextSlide()" class="btn--next btn">Next</button>
  </div>
</section>
```